# Is The Force Awakens logo a tribute to the roleplaying game?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-legends

Looking at *The Force Awakens* logo brings back old memories. The logo font of the latest movie appears to be exactly the same that was used in the titles of the [Star Wars: The Roleplaying Game, Second Edition, Revised and Expanded](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game,_Second_Edition,_Revised_and_Expanded) by [West End Games](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/West_End_Games), and its supplementary.

[image]

JJ Abrams and/or his crew probably had enough respect towards the *Legends* canon to decide to use the very same typography, out of millions of possibilities, directed to us "old-school" Star Wars fans. But do we have anything official on this?

Comment: The font in question (ITC Serif Gothic Heavy) has been used extensively in Star Wars merchandise since forever.

Comment: http://www.theverge.com/tldr/2014/11/6/7170213/itc-serif-gothic-is-the-thin-kerned-line-between-star-wars-the-verge-and-my-childhood

Comment: So, you're basically just saying they used the same font?

Comment: @RedCaio - They've used that font on loads of film posters. It's kind of an in-joke among scifi movie producers, along with the Wilhelm Scream and the "overthruster".

Comment: Looks like "No" is the right answer to my question. Thank you for the great background information, even though it kind of ruined my nostalgy... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes and no.** The font used in the roleplaying game is [ITC Serif Gothic Heavy](http://fontsup.com/font/serif-gothic-heavy.html). This font was used extensively in the original Star Wars merchandising, including (but not limited to) the roleplaying game as well as the original [movie poster](http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--oKxlCRmI--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1479841656841178253.jpg) and various press announcements along with [other Scifi films of its era](http://www.theverge.com/tldr/2014/11/6/7170213/itc-serif-gothic-is-the-thin-kerned-line-between-star-wars-the-verge-and-my-childhood).

The decision to use such a distinctive font can't possibly have been accidental and must have been stylistic, given Abrams' [stated desire](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/jj-abrams-responds-rip-criticism-853352) to take the new trilogy back to its earlier roots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The article you linked to hints at it, but doesn't state it outright, but Lubalin’s Serif Gothic family has long been a staple typeface not just for _Star Wars_, but for scifi in general, as well as for various other genres of paperback books. Several publishers’ versions of Isaac Asimov and Arthur C. Clarke books also use it, as do at least one of the issues of Erle Stanley Gardner books that I own (though variations and combinations of Franklin Gothic and Alternate Gothic seem more common there). It was a wildly popular font when originally chosen for the first _Star Wars_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I thought about a wider examination of the font's use in scifi (it was used in the 2001 poster and the trailers for Star Trek: TMP, for example) but I decided against it in the end. I've added in the Verge link if the OP (or whoever) wants to explore the topic in more detail.